# Unable to move all files except directories to a folder in terminal

Tags: directory, mv

I have extended regexes enabled in my Bash by

```
shopt -s extglob
```

They may be useful in solving the problem.

I run the following unsuccessfully, since it moves also directories

```
$ mv `find . -maxdepth 1` django-tes/
```

I am trying to find all files except directories and move them to a directory called django-tes/.

**How can you move all files except directories in a folder to a folder** in terminal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `find . -type f -maxdepth 1`